# In what condition does a class implements an interface?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

Just came out from my mind while using this statement:

```
Queue<T> q = new LinkedList<T>();
```

I understand that `Queue` is an interface and `LinkedList` class "implements" all the methods that Queue has, (`add` `remove` `peek` etc).

However, I looked at the source code of `LinkedList` (openjdk6) only to find out that the class does not explicitly implements Queue interface.

```
public class LinkedList<E>
   extends AbstractSequentialList<E>
   implements List<E>, Deque<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
```

Then I read the source code of `Deque<E>` to see that `Deque` interface extends `Queue` interface.
Does this mean that by implementing `Deque`, `LinkedList` is also implementing Queue and all of its ancestors?

Also, if I have a class that has all methods in an interface implemented, can I assign an object of that class with the interface type without using "implements" keyword?

Comment: Even if a class does not "implement" any interface but has all required method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, inheritance is transitive, with interfaces and subclasses.  I.e. if `B` extends `A` and `C` implements `B`, then `C` implements `A`.

No, what you are describing is ["duck typing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

> In computer programming with object-oriented programming languages, duck typing is a style of typing in which an object's methods and properties determine the valid semantics, rather than its inheritance from a particular class or implementation of an explicit interface.

This means that if it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, then it must be a `Duck`.  However, in Java, duck typing isn't suppported.  A class must explicitly implement an interface or extend a class to be able to be assigned to that interface type or superclass type.

Comment: duck typing! i like it

Answer (score 2):

> Then I read the source code of Deque to see that Deque interface extends Queue interface. Does this mean that by implementing Deque, LinkedList is also implementing Queue and all of its ancestors?

Yes.

<sub>As long as the implementing class is really a *concrete* class, and not an abstract one.</sub>

> Also, if I have a class that has all methods in an interface implemented, can I assign an object of that class with the interface type?

No. What you refer to is sometimes called [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). This is not directly supported by Java<sup>*</sup>. You only can assign an object of this class to the interface type *if* the interface is explicitly declared to be implemented by using the `implements` keyword somewhere in the hierarchy of the corresponding class.

---

<sup>*</sup> : As pointed out in the comments: Duck typing is not supported by the language itself. There are reflection hacks that allow certain constructs that are similar to what can be achieved in a language that *really* allows Duck-Typing.

Comment: The second part of your answer is incorrect because duck typing in Java can be achieved with reflection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Java

Comment: @clever_trevor Parts of the language are *designed* and *intended* to be used in a particular way, and reflection may be used to drill holes into these concepts. This is like saying that "Strings in Java are not immutable (because they can be modified with reflection)". The *style* of the question indicates that reflection and dynamic proxies are certainly not *appropriate* in an answer, but I'll add a hint about this, if others think that it is adequate.

Answer (score 1):

It implements Deque which extends Queue

Which means all Queue methods and all Deque methods are implemented

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html

first one yes

answer to 2nd question
you have to "declare" that you are implementing that interface

Answer (score 1):

Well, forget about interfaces and think of classes. Say your class called `MyFrame` extends `JFrame`. Is the following code true or false:

```
Object o = new MyFrame();
```

If `MyFrame` was an instance of `JFrame`, but not of `Object` (which is very wide down in the hirarchy, of course), this code won't compile. But it compiles.

Back to interfaces, this is the same. The code you wrote above will compile, but it won't compile if `LinkedList` wouldn't implement the methods of `Queue` (than it must be an abstract class, or `LinkedList` won't compile so you can't use it anyway).